# Capture Tab Click Event in Mono

Tags: xamarin.android, monodevelop

I have a Tabhost in my app with 3 tabs. The tabs are all working fine.

Now I want to perform some additional logic when the tab is selected?.

For Example: In one of my tabs, I provide an option for the user to sort things in different order and update the another tab.

how can we get the click event of TabHost?

I have updated the Tab Creation (Activity) part.

Thanks in Advance.

```
 [Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
public class TabSearch : TabActivity 
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Search_WOTab);

            /* ******************** Adding 2 Tab Controls and setting Activity classes to Tabs added ******************** */
            TabHost.TabSpec tspec;
            Intent intent;

            intent = new Intent(this, typeof(WOSearch));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            tspec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("Search");
            tspec.SetIndicator("Search", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Search));
            tspec.SetContent(intent);
            TabHost.AddTab(tspec);

            intent = new Intent(this, typeof(WOFilter));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            tspec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("Filter");
            tspec.SetIndicator("Filter", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Filter));
            tspec.SetContent(intent);
            TabHost.AddTab(tspec);                           
            TabHost.TabChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, TabHost.CurrentTab.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.InnerException.ToString(), ToastLength.Short);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [TabHost.TabChanged](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3aAndroid.Widget.TabHost.TabChanged) event.

```
tabHost.TabChanged += (sender, e) => {
                if (tabHost.CurrentTab == 0) {
                       // Do what you want.
                }
            };
```

PS: [Xamarin Docs](http://docs.xamarin.com) is your friend.

Edit:

You should modify your code to this...

```
//TabHost.TabChanged += TabHost_TabChanged;               
            TabHost.TabChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, TabHost.CurrentTab.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };
```

TabHost.CurrentTab is the index of the selected tab.

Comment: I have already tried this TabChanged event for Tabhost . But the Event didn't fired.

Comment: You havent called Show method on the Toast so you wont see anything happening. Also why have you wired up two event handlers for your code? Replace your code as I have done in my update answer above.

Comment: Still Onclick remains the same. I have updated my sample code above. Kindly verify.

Comment: I am not sure why this is not working for you. If you can upload your entire project somewhere, i will give it a try.